# How to remove ## [ ] output in r plot

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I run the following code in rmarkdown. I can generate proper plots but not happy with `##` in my printout. I was wondering if there's a way to remove them in the outcome.

```
{r, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=TRUE}
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

did3_bg1 = lm(log(assets) ~ lbg_share*bg*postreform, data = df)

plot_model(did3_bg1, type = "int")
```

And the outcome is

##[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ierKu.png)]

##[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkdId.png)]

[image]
[image]

I was wondering how to print only plot without ## outcomes.

The data is

```
structure(list(firmid = structure(c("000020", "000020", "000020", 
"000020", "000020"), label = "", format.stata = "%9s"), 
    year = structure(c(1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    postcrisis = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    postreform = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
     business_group = structure(c("DD", 
    "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD"), label = "", format.stata = "%33s"), 
    lbg30 = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    lbg = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "", format.stata = "%10.0gc"), 
    bg = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    size = structure(c("", "", "", "", ""), label = "", format.stata = "%12s"), 
    top30share = structure(c(0.52592396736145, 0.51882940530777, 
    0.538980901241302, 0.560082197189331, 0.585784077644348), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    lbg_share = structure(c(0.739427030086517, 0.739992499351501, 
    0.753883957862854, 0.762438356876373, 0.773166179656982), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    bg_share = structure(c(0.836483478546143, 0.831545650959015, 
    0.840154886245728, 0.84471720457077, 0.849978506565094), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    top30sharei = structure(c(0.451163440942764, 0.462957829236984, 
    0.505831837654114, 0.530933856964111, 0.54751318693161), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    lbg_sharei = structure(c(0.654736995697021, 0.662965774536133, 
    0.692618787288666, 0.699759483337402, 0.70341295003891), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    bg_sharei = structure(c(0.787293970584869, 0.789016127586365, 
    0.810981154441833, 0.814838707447052, 0.815460205078125), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    assets = structure(c(12150840320, 15652244480, 16448676864, 
    19630718976, 29004148736), format.stata = "%9.0g"),format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Is your function `plot_model` printing empty output? It looks like you're getting empty output 4 times.

Comment: @NikhilHaksar, No in fact I got 4 figures but in the post I omitted rest three of them. Let me modify the post.

Comment: Got it. If your function `plot_model` isn't returning something, this behavior is strange. Just looked at some plots I made in RMarkdown recently and they don't have the R output above the plot.

Comment: @NikhilHaksar, I just modified the post.

Comment: Ah, I see. `plot_model` is a function from `sjPlot`. Does adding the option `results=FALSE` to your chunk options fix the issue?

Comment: @NikhilHaksar, No it is the same.

Comment: Where is a problem, i can't understand. And add your data, it is not reproducible.

Comment: @manro, nothing wrong in the code, only print issue. The codes generate the figures with ## [1] and ##[2] which indicate the figure number. I want to simply print figures without ##[1] and ##[2].

Comment: @joe add the data, I can see now

Comment: @manro, yes, I did it.

Comment: @joe some data is still missing... But i have tried to knit some examples from there: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.4.1/topics/plot_model ...and if you add ```{r, warning = FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}``` "##" aren't displayed.

Comment: @manro As you may see my post, I already tried those options but ## is still there. Let me revise my data right away.